# Rock envire - vizkit3d : Change environment visualization (envire lib) from ruby script

Tags: rock

I am using a ruby script to connent the Multi Layer Surface Map of the velodyne_slam component to the vizkit3D visualization.

The visualizazion plugin is loaded like this:
envireViz = Vizkit.default_loader.EnvireVisualization

It is possible to get the MLSVisualisation object from the EnvireVisualization in order to set visualization properties (like colors etc.) from the ruby script?

Rubys introspection abilities didn't help a lot here...

Comment: deleted comment here, moved under the answer

Answer (score 1):

That is currently not implemented. The Envire visualization plugins are all handled and updated by one Envire Vizkit plugin.

But since the Envire visualization plugins became QObjects too it would be possible to add a qt slot method to get an instance of the envire plugins, where the properties can be accessed.

Comment: I just pushed the changes to make it possible myself (added a getVisualizer function).

envireViz = Vizkit.default_loader.EnvireVisualization
mlsviz = 
envireViz.getVisualizer("envire::MLSVisualization");
   if (mlsviz != nil)
      mlsviz.cycle_height_color = 0
    else
      puts "MLSViz == nil"
    end